# Getting the Current Adress using GPS in android?

Tags: android, geolocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Hi i wanted to know that can i get the location adress or Longitude or latitude.. just for once and that it then turns off the GPS..the activity will not be a map activity..explaning the code working will be appreciated more...Thank YOu

Comment: No downvote. Please do a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Using+GPS+to+get+current+address+in+Android) before posting new question. And please read the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to know the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Use GeoCoder api, to get Location from Location, see following link

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/02/get-address-from-location-using.html